# How to store template type in structure

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;
template <class Key, class Value>
struct st
{
        typedef Key KeyType;
        typedef Value ValueType;
};
int main()
{
        st<int, int> st1;
        if(typeid(st1.KeyType) == typeid(int))
                cout<<"Yes";
        return 0;
}
```

Is there a way of storing the type `Key` and `Value` within the structure? Like st1 structure stores key of type `int` and value of type `int` or any template type within the structure. i want to later use it for type comparison. i get the following error.

```
 invalid use of ‘st<int, int>::KeyType’
  if(typeid(st1.KeyType) == typeid(int))
```

I want to store the type with which was it initialized to to stored within the structure.

Comment: Did you try to just do it? Because, the answer is, yes, of course.

Comment: Are you asking how to store members of type `Key` and `Value` in the template class? Or are you asking how to define type aliases for the types `Key` and `Value` in the template class?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that makes you think you need to do something like this? Please clarify.

Comment: if i can have the type within the structure. i can use it for type comparison.

Comment: What comparison? Don't omit details. How are we supposed to know what you need to accomplish?

Comment: @RaghuDV it is very unclear of what you are asking. Please try to refer to Maarten Bamelis and StoryTeller comments and edit your question...

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: that's an assignment not a == in the line mentioned in the error

Comment: @ROX oops. corrected.

Comment: @StoryTeller if i have a `st<int, int> st1` st1 have key and value type as `int, int` . `st1` for me defines the type of key-store. the way i identify the key-store is by name. All the info is stored in structure on instantiate of key-store. I want to validate the provided type of key-value actually matches with the key-store, rather than doing read and write blindly and throw exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++11 or newer, you can use `decltype`

```
    if ( typeid(decltype(st1)::KeyType) == typeid(int) )
            cout<<"Yes";
```

or, better IMHO, `std::is_same` (evaluated compile-time)

```
    if ( std::is_same<decltype(st1)::KeyType, int>::value )
            cout<<"Yes";
```

If you can use C++17, the last example can be written as

```
    if constexpr ( std::is_same<decltype(st1)::KeyType, int>::value )
            cout<<"Yes";
```

so the `cout << "Yes"` is compiled or not according the `value` of `std::is_same`.

Comment: what is `::value` can you help me understand?

Comment: Got it, Thanks dude...

Comment: @RaghuDV - `value` is a `bool` const value (`constexpr`, to be more precise) that is `true` when the first and the second type are the same and `false` otherwise. Unfortunately it's only available starting from C++11. More details [in this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score 0):

you could use typedefs or the newer alternative:-

```
using KeyType = int;
```

(edit after edit to question)
 it might be overkill for your simple example, but given your real use wont be as simple as that, you could consider deriving from 2 structs

```
template <typename keyType>
struct KeyedType 
{};

template <typename containedType>
struct Container{};

template < typename keyType, typename containedType >
struct st : public KeyedType<keyType> , Container<containedType>
{
    // etc
};
```

then you can use dynamic cast to do the comparison.

```
st<int, int> st1;
if(dynamic_cast<KeyedType<int>*>(&st1) )
```

It's a bit odd to have to be taking the address to get a pointer to st1 having held st1 by value, but if you're not using st1 polymorphically though then you ought to know what type it was  (unless the reason for the type being unknown is that the code is inside a template in which case use :: on the type itself as already stated in other answers/comments)

If you do make this change though, you might be able to avoid doing the type comparison totally (but that depends on things not in the question)

Comment: yes, which can be used for type comparison, not as a string.

Comment: @RaghuDV string? You didn't mention strings. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Lets say i have a template type <T> that is defined for the structure. Can i store this `T` within the structure.

Comment: yes: using someGoodNameForWhatTis = T;

Comment: Note that [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) are C++11 or later. Since the question is only tagged C++, it might be useful to provide examples of both the `typedef` and `using` alternative.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis on the other hand it is tagged C++ and not C++03 nor C++98...

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Also, the current version of C++ is C++14, if you are asking about some specific, older standard, then say so or tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Key` and `Value` instead of the explicit `std::string` and `int` types in the structure template:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
struct st
{
    Key name;
    Value permission;   
};
```

Or maybe your need to refer to these types in other places in code? Then you can use `typedef`s in the template, e.g.:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
struct st
{
    typedef Key   KeyType;
    typedef Value ValueType;

    ...
};
```

Comment: how to access `KeyType` using the structure

Comment: @RaghuDV: Suppose that you have `typedef st<int, double> S1;`. Then you can use `S1::KeyType` and that would be `int`.

Comment: Yes you got it. S1 is not a class or namespace to use it with`::`.

Comment: @RaghuDV: What kind of code are you compiling? Have you tried the S1 typedef as written in my previous comment?

Comment: @RaghuDV BTW I noted you edited your question adding my answer with typedefs inside the struct template.